# Why do two directories differ after syncing with rsync?

Tags: rsync, diff

I copied some directories on one removable drive to another removable one using rsync.
The command used was:

```
rsync -avPS <source> <destination>
```

rsync doesn't report any errors.

After syncing I used diff on some random directories to check for differences or errors. The synced files are apparently identical (checked with a simple `ls -lh`), nevertheless diff reports that they differ.

```
diff <source_dir> <destination_dir>
```

The files are all RAW photo files and their sidecar files (text files).

What could be the reason for the file differences?

**EDIT:**

The filesystems are
(partial output from `fdisk -l`):

- SRC:

`/dev/sdb1            2048  1953521663   976759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

- DST:

`/dev/sdd1              63  1953520064   976760001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT`

---

This is the output of `ls -l`:

- SRC:

`-rw------- 1 twan twan 177556828 Apr 19 12:38 20160403101701-07.tiff`

- DST:

`-rw------- 1 twan twan 177556828 Apr 19 12:38 20160403101701-07.tiff`

---

Here is the output of `diff` for this specific file:

`Binary files /media/twan/GrafxMedia/photos/hdr/20160403101701-07.tiff and ./20160403101701-07.tiff differ`

Comment: Clarifications please. 1. Removable media - you did unmount it before unplugging? 2. Please provide examples of the differences reported by `diff` and the corresponding sameness suggested by `ls -lh`.

Comment: what type of filesystems are the source and destination?  ext4? xfs? FAT? NTFS?

Comment: Run `cmp -l /media/twan/GrafxMedia/photos/hdr/20160403101701-07.tiff and ./20160403101701-07.tiff` to get a list of differing bytes. Did the file already exist on the destination before you ran `rsync`? Did you ever unplug that disk before the operating system had reported that it had finished unmounting?

Comment: This does rather look like a disk that was unplugged before being unmounted

Comment: Can I somehow check if the disk was unplugged before unmounting? This is a home PC, family members have access to it.. At least then I know what the cause could be. No harm done, I still have all files.